# Odd behavior of forward slashes in helm-buffers-list patterns

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

When filtering the results of `helm-buffers-list` or `helm-for-files`, as soon as I type a forward slash, Helm seems to switch from filtering results as expected to showing *all* buffers:

[image]

It seems to highlight some letters in the buffers list, but I don't see any logic or pattern behind this behavior.

I'm not sure why this happens. Is it a bug? Is it some special syntax I'm not aware of? Fuzzy matching is off as far as I can tell.

Comment: While helm matches buffers,  `/` is used to match directory name, you can find some info on this with `C-h m` (which is already displayed in helm's mode-line). And you also need a blank space before and after `/`, otherwise helm doesn't filter any buffer, for example, as you can see `dmd/src` is matching all buffers.

Comment: That's only if you start the search with `/`. According to the documentation, at least.

Comment: If I add blank spaces around `/`, then `locate` no longer works. Having to type different patterns to search within subsets of results makes no sense.

Comment: Different sources have different ways to interpret your search pattern and they may and may not work well at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [it was a bug](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1462#issuecomment-206889312), [now fixed](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/9722df2be9ebcacf1f782bf8ee8f9c4b757c238d).

Comment: Could you please accept this answer so we can mark this question as resolved?